# How to click a button in html within an iframe using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I need to extract some values from a website, and to do so, I have to click on a button on that page. However, there seems to be an issue. I noticed that when I hit F12, I can identify the specific tag, class, XPath, and so forth, but when I use "CTRL+U" and attempt to find that button, it's not visible. I'm not sure why this happens, but okay.

This is the website:

> https://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/negociacao/renda-variavel/empresas-listadas.htm

When I execute the following code:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-companies-home/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/app-companies-home -filter-name/form/div/div[4]/button').click()
```

Essentially, I'm trying to simulate a click on the button labeled "TODOS",
whose tag is:

```
<button type="submit" aria-label="Buscar Todas" class="btn btn-light btn-block mt-3">Todos</button>
```

and the FULL XPATH path is:

```
/html/body/app-root/app-companies-home/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/app-companies-home-filter-name/form/div/div[4]/button
```

However, I receive this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/app-root/app-companies-home/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/app-companies-home-filter-name/form/div/div[4]/button"}
```

It seems that the HTML element isn't being found, despite its visibility when pressing F12. Any advice on how to resolve this issue?

This is my full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=None, options=chrome_options)
driver.get(
    "https://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/negociacao/renda-variavel/empresas-listadas.htm"
)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH,
    "/html/body/app-root/app-companies-home/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/app-companies-home-filter-name/form/div/div[4]/button",
).click()
```

I tried to use other ways to use `find_element()` but without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element <kbd>Todos</kbd> is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/negociacao/renda-variavel/empresas-listadas.htm")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#bvmf_iframe")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Buscar Todas']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/negociacao/renda-variavel/empresas-listadas.htm")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='bvmf_iframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Buscar Todas']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Todos]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: I used these imports and work:


from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

Comment: @GabrielMenezes yeap, you are perfecto.